# как правильно - "е*ала" или "е*ола"?

Tags: грамматика, словообразование, обсценная-лексика

Обсценная лексика!

Периодически встречаю в качестве существительного ("какая-то еб*ла", например), видел оба примера написания, стало интересно, теоретически, в соответствии с правилами словообразования - какая гласная должна быть вместо *? Не знаю, где еще можно спросить, в словарях, по понятным причинам, такой записи нет.

Comment: -ол- суффикс Словообразовательная единица, образующая имена существительные, которые обозначают химические вещества и препараты, предназначенные для воздействия на вещества, предметы и болезни... и мат не обсценная лексика.

Comment: Да уж, про химию я знаю. Но здесь скорее Л – суффикс и перегласовка А/О. А это из Сети.  "Что такое ненормативная лексика? Это определенный сегмент лексики, который включает в себя вульгарные, грубые и непристойные бранные выражения, выражающие в большинстве случаев спонтанную реакцию на неприятную и неожиданную ситуацию. Сюда относится матерщина, жаргонные слова.
Такого рода слова ещё называют обсценными, от латинского obscenus — непристойный, грязный, бесстыдный. Одной из разновидностей обсценных слов является русский мат".

Comment: @Sharon проблема в том, что в русском можно обругать человека вполне себе обычными словами. Мат - табуированные слова, но причина табу даже не их открытая сексуальность, а иная, и уж точно не обсценность. Кроме того, матом можно шутить, а обсценными словами шутить не получится. Мат табуируется в основном из-за несерьезности говорящего, когда это может касаться серьезной темы, ну и на мат обычно сложно что-то возразить, то есть мат - это такие стоп- или антислова, антиязык. Насчёт Л, ну возможно, есть же еще слово ебо-бо, созвучное с клоунским ти-би-бо, но имеет значение "дурачок", "придурок".

Comment: ебо-бо - обсц., шутл. или неодобр. неадекватный человек ◆ Отсутствует пример употребления (см. рекомендации). Педивикия. 
То есть, как обсценное слово может быть *неодобрительным или шутливым*? Попробуйте с помощью слова fuck неодобрить что-то... или слова bitch или курва - скорее получится наоборот одобрение, как у нас любят говорить сейчас "шлюшка". Отсюда простой вывод, мат вполне может стоять на защите морали и моральных ценностей, а вот "обсценная лексика" - нет. То есть мат - ценная лексика, а не обесценивающая.

Comment: Есть русская поговорка: слово - серебро, молчание - золото. Мат может быть употреблён, когда нужно прекратить разговор или обсуждение темы. То есть, если все слова серебряные, то есть мат - это предзолотое слово.

Comment: Спасибо! Всегда узнаю от вас много интересного и нового.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что верна форма **е*ола.**

**Е*ола** — это переосмысление слова ***эбола*** — тропическая лихорадка.

Значение: что-то **плохое** или что-то **непонятное**.

Неприличный смысл и **экспрессию** придает замена  букв **Э/Е.**

Подробно **[здесь](https://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/239-chto-takoe-ebola.html).**

**Е*ала** — это бОльшая **вульгаризация** слова: ***А*** — тематический суффикс, ***Л*** — суффикс прошедшего времени, окончание ***А*** для  сущ. общего рода.

Экспрессия та же, но слово более **непристойно.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ от 09.11.2023 (по коментариям)**

**В чем логика?**  Форма заимствованная, но при этом наполненная новым содержанием, вот в чем **ЛОГИКА.** Аналогичный случай **с фиговым листочком**, просто один к одному.

Форма как эвфемизм, можно так сказать? Эвфемизм — ]греч.[/p] ευφήμη 'говорить доброзначащие речи'. Слово, служащее заменой табуированному слову (табу) или для смягчения обозначения, которое говорящему представляется грубым или неуместным... И вот форма здесь (всего-то один звук!) **СМЯГЧАЕТ** это содержание. Про него и вопрос был.

Comment: фигов листочек это фразеологизм, а не новое, заимствованное слово. В мате нет ни одного заимствования, но я согласен, что слово е*ала непростое даже с точки зрения словообразования. Ну и приведите уже наконец примеры вашего механизма смягчения заиствования, а то механизм есть а примеров нет, нехорошо.

Comment: Фигов листочек стал позже фразеологизмом, но в действительности это эвфемизм, заменяющий неприличное слово. Смягченный до предела, даже в словарях есть: на фиг (сниж.). Перенос значения по внешнему виду.  С эболой то же самое.  Перенос по сходству звукового и буквенного состава, но при этом охранено исходное значение  (что-то непонятное или неприятное). Заменили только одну букву — и вот уже узнаваемое слово, но в смягченном варианте. Ведь полного звукового состава нет.

Comment: В итоге получаем слова: нейтральное (Эбола) — полунепристойное (е*Ола)  — совсем непристойное (е*Ала). Выбирайте любой вариант смягченности.  Можете даже звук Б пропустит, все равно созвучие будет)

Answer (score 2):

Эбола тут конечно ни при чем. [Е*ала](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D0%B0%D1%88) появилась задолго до эболы. Правильно через а, корень -еб-, суффикс -а- и далее -л-. [См тут](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0)
. Не путать с суффиксом [-ал-](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D0%B0%D0%BB). А кстати почему нет ? Потому что полно всяких слов типа -е%ало-,-e%ать- итд, в которых суффикс -а-. Кстати, суффикс -а- иногда может быть не суффиксом, а незначимым соединительным элементом и варьироваться с -о-, например умалишенный\умолишенный. Найдем теперь аналоги этого словообразования в РЯ, то есть слова женского рода с двумя суффиксами -а- и -л-, обозначающие не субъекта действия (всякие кидалы, вышибалы). Опачки, а нет таких слов. Так что морфемика этого слова в словаре под сомнением, у него нет аналогов!

Теперь рассмотрим схему образования у е%ола. Суффикс [-ол-](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D0%BE%D0%BB) в РЯ существует, но там одно только нормальное слово пердолить (этанолы не берем), остается двойной суффикс -о- и -л-, ну найдите такие слова в русском языке - их нет. Но нет и вообще слов с корнем -еб- и суффиксом -о-. Так что, этот вариант, точно не вариант. Вы скажете, а как же всякие там е%ошня, гандошня, пиз%ошня%. А вот как:

Словообразование у [е%ашить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (суффикс [аш](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D0%B0%D1%88) пташка, алкаш)
и [е%ошить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (суффикс [ош](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D0%BE%D1%88): юноша, жопошник, святоша)

То есть тут суффиксы -аш- и -ош-, таких слов навалом в РЯ, так что все в рамках нормы (нормальных рамках).

Comment: Абсолютно поддерживаю. Настаиваю на правильности этого ответа. Альтернативный предложенный вообще не выдерживает критики.

Comment: Я, безусловно, не авторитет в практической области обсценной лексики,  Мой (альтернативный) вариант взят из Интернета, у меня хотя бы ссылка есть. А вы чем докажете правильность этого ответа и вашего альтернативного варианта?  Про семантику здесь ничего не сказано, одна "физиология", а слово может переосмысливаться и приобретать новое значение:  что-то плохое или что-то непонятное. Чтобы АБСОЛЮТНО настаивать, одного желания мало. Приведите информацию из источников, дайте ссылки и обзор темы.  Я пока вижу не КРИТИКУ, а ваше личное мнение.

Comment: Это форум лингвистический, поэтому надо соответствовать. То есть видеть в этой теме языковой материал и грамотно его оценивать.  Также расширять тему вопроса не надо. Спросили про конкретное слово, вот и отвечайте точно по этой теме,

Comment: а можете пояснить, почему вам кажется вариант с "а" правильным, если вы упоминаете, что слова с "о" тоже существуют?

Comment: Ну тут в суффиксах дело, корень -еб- у всех глаголов, а далее варианты суффиксов аш\ош могут быть, но не ал\ол, найдите в РЯ глаголы с суффиксом -ол-, с суффиксом -ал- полно - "он намотал" например. А далее добавляем окончание -а- и из глагола получаем существительное.

Comment: Третий глаз, ну все мы знаем что за персонаж шарон. Ссылка епти у неё есть. Приведите млять информацию. Эти агрументы не выдерживают никакой критики, как и все её собственные рассуждения.

Comment: в общем поправил ответ, там как всегда все немного глубже оказалось если копнуть

Comment: Слов много, но я не вижу словообразовательной цепочки с обозначением суффиксов. Главный вопрос – откуда формант ОЛ?  Это вы или не объяснили. или я не поняла. Как бывает языке – это  не так интересно. Интересно, как здесь появился звук О? Выглядит  пришельцем, образно говоря.

Comment: Интересно как раз как бывает. Если показать, что так не бывает, то с еб%олой вопрос решается автоматически.

Comment: Автоматически, да. Делаем вывод: это слово заимствованное, а  не образованной в русском языке.  Эбола – это одна из версий.

Comment: 1. Как может слово с корнем -еб- быть заимствованным, а не образованным?? Где логика? Тогда уж корень другой был бы. 2. Приведите хоть один пример заимствованного в русском мате. Все богатство русского мата - образованное, а не заимствованное. Поэтому он такой и богатый. Снова - где логика?